# Run function on click in an specific container

Tags: javascript

I have two questions:

First how can i change this function, so that it will be triggerd when the user clicks on the div with the id "canvascontent":

```
Event.add(window, "load", function() {
```

And more important how can i define that the function of the button below is only triggerd when the function of above has been triggerd first?

```
<input type="button" onclick="sketch.toDataURL()" style="" value="Speichern">
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's `Event.add`?  Have you tried replacing `window` with `document.getElementById('canvascontent')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event.Add` isn't a thing, but the [Event object is](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

```
//Set a variable so both functions have scope to it.
var canvasClicked = false;

//Add the 'click' event to the DOM element "canvascontent"
//You could also use .addEventListener()
document.getElementById("canvascontent").onclick = function(e) {
    //do whatever
    canvasClicked = true;
};

//Call sketch data when the button is clicked
function sketchData() {
    //only sketch to the DataURL if the canvas has been clicked.
    if (canvasClicked) {
        sketch.toDataURL()
    }
}
```

And then...

```
<input type="button" onclick="sketchData()" style="" value="Speichern">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of what you want to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        var buttonClicked = false;
        function load()
        {
            //Adds the event handler dynamicly. Could also be written in html like so:
            // <div id="canvascontent" onclick="divClick()">
            var div = document.getElementById("canvascontent");
            div.setAttribute('onclick', 'divClick()')
        }

        function buttonClick()
        {
            if (buttonClicked == true)
            {
                alert("DONE");
                sketch.toDataURL();
            }
        }

        function divClick()
        {
            buttonClicked = true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <div id="canvascontent">
        Content of div
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="buttonClick()" style="" value="Speichern">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `div.setAttribute('onclick', 'divClick()')` should really be `div.addEventListener('click', divClick)`.